# Entity Framework Where Any Column Contains

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

When writing a where condition on an Entity Framework context object, is there a shorthand way of testing all the columns, sort of like this:

```
context.tableName.where(t => t.AnyColumn.Contains(...))
```

Or am I forced to test each column individually?

Comment: In pure SQL, there is no such a ready-to-go functionality; and not surprisingly there is no equivalent in EF too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box way to do that but you can write your own method which will use reflection to get the list of your model's properties and check each of them

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is possible you may have to search each field individually, but why not search for a value in a specific column instead of searching the whole table, it reduces the room for error and makes for a quicker query